# How Can I Add Somethink To MongoDB list object , [ PyMongo ]

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Here is my code :

```py
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:****/")
db = client['StoreF']
column = db['base_shop']
column.update_one(({'id': 2}), {"$post": {'Products': {"PSF": 11}}})
```

But it changes

[image]

That PSF but I want to add more items like PSF: `11 > NextLine > PS5: 15`

What should I Do?  What should I write instead of `$post`?

Comment: in object you can save one key name like PSF .
please explain more

Comment: What is `"$post"`?  Would you show a "before" update document and the "after"/desired updated document?

Answer (score 0):

you could try changing the method from update to insert

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:****/")
db = client['StoreF']
column = db['base_shop']
column.insert_one(({'id': 2}), {"$post": {'Products': {"PSF": 11}}})
```

Comment: It Gives Error:

pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: StoreF.base_shop index: __primary_key__ dup key: { id: 2 }, full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'keyPattern': {'id': 1}, 'keyValue': {'id': 2}, 'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: StoreF.base_shop index: __primary_key__ dup key: { id: 2 }'}

Comment: This is not a good answer. Poor design choice to replace `update` with `delete data`.